# presentingViewController is nil when using presentViewController:animated:completion: in iOS 8

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios8

Wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue recently...

For one of my view controllers , only on iOS 8, after calling `presentViewController:animated:completion:`, the presented view controller has `self.presentingController` as nil. It is fine on iOS7, and also does not happen on another view controller.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/presentingViewController) says that it should be set, as long as the presented view controller was presented modally. Given it works in iOS 7, could this be an iOS 8 bug?

I've been able to get around it using a view container containment approach, but it would be good if someone has seen this before and knows the root cause that triggered this behaviour.

thanks

Comment: Where did you log this. It's not null in viewWillAppear, or viewDidAppear, but is in viewDidLoad. I don't remember if that's different from iOS 7.

Comment: The presented controller is a 3rd party one which i don't have access to step through (FBFriendPickerViewController). I'm seeing it as nil when i hit a breakpoint on the line after the call to `presentViewController:animated:completion:` from the presenting controller's code breakpoint

Answer (score 54):

Had a similar issue with iOS 8, where `presentingController` is nil when checking the value in `viewDidLoad`.

When `viewDidLoad` is called, there is no guarantee that the view controller hierarchy is loaded in the navigation tree. Moving the logic to a later stage (for example: `viewWillAppear`) should resolve that issue as `presentingController` should be loaded by then.

Comment: This helped me out. I needed a pointer to the `presentingViewController` in a function. I created a property, access, and store a pointer to `presentingViewController` in `viewDidAppear` for use later.

Comment: This saved me so much hair-pulling - thanks! My assumption is that this value would be set at viewdidload